# Thread safety in Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, asynchronous, slick, slick-3.0

I have a general understanding question about how Slick/the database manage asynchronous operations. When I compose a query, or an action, say

```
(for {
  users <- UserDAO.findUsersAction(usersInput.map(_.email))
  addToInventoriesResult <- insertOrUpdate(inventoryInput, user)  
  deleteInventoryToUsersResult <- inventoresToUsers.filter(_.inventoryUuid === inventoryInput.uuid).delete if addToInventoriesResult == 1
  addToInventoryToUsersResult <- inventoresToUsers ++= users.map(u => DBInventoryToUser(inventoryInput.uuid, u.uuid)) if addToInventoriesResult == 1 
} yield(addToInventoriesResult)).transactionally
```

Is there a possibility that another user can for example remove the users just after the first action `UserDAO.findUsersAction(usersInput.map(_.email))` is executed, but before the rest, such that the insert will fail (because of foreign key error)? Or a scenario that can lead to a lost update like: transaction A reads data, then transaction B updates this data, then transaction A does an update based on what it did read, it will not see B's update an overwrite it

I think this probably depends on the database implementation or maybe JDBC, as this is sent to the database as a block of SQL, but maybe Slick plays a role in this. I'm using MySQL.

In case there are synchronisation issues here, what is the best way to solve this?. I have read about approaches like a background queue that processes the operations sequentially (as semantic units), but wouldn't this partly remove the benefit of being able to access the database asynchronously -> have bad performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if the underlying database driver is blocking (the case with JDBC based drivers) then Slick cannot deliver async peformance in the truly non-blocking sense of the word (i.e. a thread will be consumed and blocked for however long it takes for a given query to complete).

There's been talk of implementing non-blocking drivers for Oracle and SQL Server (under a paid Typesafe subscription) but that's not happening any time soon AFAICT. There are a [couple of projects](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async) that do provide non-blocking drivers for Postegres and MySQL, but YMMV, still early days.

With that out of the way, when you call `transactionally` Slick takes the batch of queries to execute and wraps them in a try-catch block with underlying connection's `autocommit` flag set to false. Once the queries have executed successfully the transaction is committed by setting `autocommit` back to the default, true. In the event an Exception is thrown, the connection's `rollback` method is called. Just standard JDBC session boilerplate that Slick conveniently abstracts away.

As for your scenario of a user being deleted mid-transaction and handling that correctly, that's the job of the underlying database/driver.

Comment: *a thread will be consumed and blocked* this means that still there could be n threads accessing the database concurrently (where max n is probably my thread pool size)? I'm worried only about overwriting updates - which I think can't be solved only by using transactions. If transaction A reads some data, then transaction B updates this data, then transaction A does an update based on what it did read, it will not see B's update an overwrite it. Can this happen? If yes how is this addressed with Slick?

Comment: Slick maintains its own internal thread pool (on top of default pool, HikariCP) which `DBIO`, for example, depends on to do its streaming/batching operations. Slick itself does not prevent the transactionA/transactionB scenario from occurring since they are (presumably) separate non-nested transactions. As long as the underlying database is thread safe then it should be able to correctly manage your  transactionA/transactionB scenario (i.e. fail transactionB)

Comment: Do you know if MySQL is thread safe? I read that it requires sometimes table locking so not sure about this. If it's not thread safe do I understand correctly that there's nothing I can do from Slick side? Thanks for all the infos so far.

Comment: huh, I assumed that via HikariCP (and other JDBC connection pools that correctly implement the spec) thread safety is guaranteed at the driver level (i.e. one thread per connection). But according to [this github issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1181) that may not always be the case. At any rate, you might want to ping Slick's author on github or gitter to see what measures Slick takes to guarantee thread safe access.

Comment: Ok, from that issue it looks like at the end the thread safety comes from Slick? I'll ask in gitter when I have time. +1 but letting this open as it would be nice to have a complete answer, also for other people to read.